# Angular HTTP request return 406

Tags: angular, interceptor, angular-httpclient

I have this simple code for an HTTP request:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  // add authorization header with jwt token if available
  request = this.addTokenToRequest(request);
  return next.handle(request)
  .pipe(
    catchError(error => {
      switch (error) {
              case 'Not Acceptable': {
                return this.handle406Error(request, next);
                break;
              }
              case 'Unauthorized': {
                // return this.handle401Error(request, next);
                break;
              }
        }
    }));
```

}

I am getting 406 back because I am deliberately working with an expired token. But error I am getting is = "OK". According to my code I was getting  "Not Acceptable". Any idea about it?

Thanks

Here is how it looks like:
[image]

Update. Here is how the Response object looks like when it's returned from the same app by with AngularJS front-end:

```
config: {method: "GET", transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: 
Array(1), jsonpCallbackParam: "callback", paramSerializer: ƒ, …}
data: "Unauthenticated Token."
headers: ƒ (d)
status: 406
statusText: "Not Acceptable"
xhrStatus: "complete
```

Comment: not THE solution, but what i would do here is add a bunch of debugging console logs and check what the values are. in your case apperantly your error="OK" right?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Not sure I understand what you are proposing.

Comment: did you confirm that your error = "OK" in code? if not i suggest doing "console.log(error)" right before the switch statement and check your browser's console when running that request (i assume you use this code in a web app which you navigate using a browser). additionally you can do "console.log('random text')" inside the cases to see for sure which case is triggered.

Comment: I added a screenshot from the console.

Comment: ok i dove a bit deeper into this and found https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23334 and skimming through this it seems that "OK" is some sort of default status text. What you can do, to confirm if its the "actual OK-Response" is console.log(error.ok) which in your case is supposed to output "false". additionally you can console.log(error.status) to check the status code number. i suggest you actually console.log it instead of running a debugger because it seems to me that the debugger doesnt show the error as an object but rather just displays the string representation of it

Comment: looking at the angular doc for HttpErrorResponse https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse we can see that "OK" is in fact a default value (under constructor, string="OK"). not sure if with error 406 this default value is applied.

Comment: Like I said, I was getting a different value, no changes on backend whatsoever.

Comment: im not doubting that. all im saying is to try to console.log everything instead of looking at the debugger output, because the "error" variable here is supposed to be a object but your debugger displays only the string portion of it

Comment: From console: OK as a result of console.log(error);

Comment: So "error" is in fact just a string. i thought that it was actually an instance of HttpErrorResponse. now this changes a lot of things. seems like there is something going on in the backend of things

Comment: And I totally agree. It comes from the server. My question why it's "Ok" now while a day ago or so it was "Not acceptable". Also if Console shows it as 406, why my code doesn't see as 406?

Answer (score 0):

If the error is returned as a string the http response status is going to be a success status(2XX)  and this code will not work but the checks need to be on the response part using tap function of the rxjs, but if it is not then the code bellow is going to work for you:

```
 intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      // add authorization header with jwt token if available
      request = this.addTokenToRequest(request);
      return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(
        catchError(error => {
     if(error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          switch (error.status) {
                  case '406': {
                   console.log('HttpResponseError with status 406');
                   console.log(of(error));
                   return this.handle406Error(request, next);
                   break;
                  }
                  case '401': {
                    // return this.handle401Error(request, next);
                    console.log('HttpResponseError with status 401')
                    break;
                  }
           default: {
                    return of(error);
                    break;
                  }
            }
      else{
           console.log('My error is not an HttpErrorResponse');

           console.log(error);
             }
         }

        }));
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I can try, but I am not sure that will help because "error instanceof HttpErrorResponse"  will fail since my error object is just a string with a value of "OK"

Comment: The response looks like this: "Unauthenticated Token."

Comment: Good now, tell me are just returning a simple string ? Or an HttpErrorResponse?

Comment: Seems like just a string. I didn't write the backend code. All I need at this point is to be able to identify 406. I was getting "Not acceptable". Dont understand why now it is "OK".

Comment: Have you changed the expiration time of the token in your backed ?

Comment: Please share your backend maybe you are just skipping a check

Comment: Yes, it is set to one minute. So, it's expired a long time ago, which is what the backend is telling me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202333/discussion-between-youssef-tounoussi-and-mark).